# Building OpenCV 3 cuda errors

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, building

I want to build **OpenCV 3.2** for *Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10 with Cuda* support. So, I configured it using *CMake* (see configuration file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wvDyuZ1AkzODh5SHhFRlJISDA/view?usp=sharing)). Cuda is installed and the path variable is set correctly. However, when building the `OpenCV.sln` solution (debug, x64), I get in total 36 (3 different) errors, all referring to the cuda module:

> C2610 C2535 C2382

Here one example per error code (Code, Description,    Project File,   Line):

> Error C2610   'std::tuple::tuple(const std::tuple
>   &)': is not a special member function which can be defaulted
>   (compiling source file
>   C:\Users\user\down\opencv3.2\opencv-src\modules\cudawarping\perf\perf_warping.cpp)    opencv_perf_cudawarping C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple 607
>
> Error C2535   'std::tuple
>   &std::tuple::operator
>   =(const std::tuple
>   &)': member function already defined or declared (compiling source
>   file
>   C:\Users\user\down\opencv3.2\opencv-src\modules\cudawarping\perf\perf_warping.cpp)    opencv_perf_cudawarping C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple 756
>
> Error C2382   'std::tuple::operator
>   =': redefinition; different exception specifications (compiling source file
>   C:\Users\user\down\opencv3.2\opencv-src\modules\cudawarping\perf\perf_warping.cpp)    opencv_perf_cudawarping C:\Users\user\down\opencv3.2\opencv-src\modules\ts\include\opencv2\ts\cuda_perf.hpp 76

**EDIT:**

This is reported as an [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7992) for OpenCV 3.2.

Here is a good way to bypass the problem, posted by [ThorbjornSomod (see issue)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7992):

> I actually got it to work both on my laptop and my desktop (GTX960M
>   and GTX970 respectively) running with OpenCV 3.2 and the latest
>   version of CUDA 8.0 for Win10 in Visual Studio 15 Community! What I
>   did was to enable WITH_CUBLAS aswell as WITH_CUDA. I also turned off
>   BUILD_PERF_TESTS and BUILD_TESTS. The configuration was built using
>   the Visual Studio 14 2015 C++ compiler.

Comment: This s not a CUDA question, it is an OpenCV  problem which has been reported several times to their bug tracker, if you bother to search for it. I am removing  the CUDA tag, please do not re-add it.

Comment: @talonmies I have seen these bug reports - but these are referring to previous versions of OpenCV 3 - and these errors had been fixed now.

Comment: @black I have encountered the same issue. To solve it, should BLAS be installed first or just check the WITH_BLAS flag?